# Joomla contact mail goes to spam folder

Tags: email, joomla, spam

currently am using joomla 1.5.22 and recently this problem is accuring if an client sends an mail via contact then it goes straight to spam folder. Can anyone help me change the mail.php or send me the file so the problem dissapears.

Thanks.

Comment: You're using an outdated version of Joomla, therefore an older and outdated version of PHPMailer. First try upgrading to Joomla 1.5.26 and if this doesn't solve any issues, please consider migrating to 3.x. If you're using any 3rd party extensions for your contact form, make sure they are up to date. What ever you do, **do not** start editing core Joomla files

Comment: thank you for the quick response, is there an alternative solution without migrating? or maybe an an 3trd party extension that does work?

Answer (score -1):

Some time these types of problem comes with the installed plugin, you can use EmailAsUsername - Remove Usernames Joomla extension, which is also very good extension.

Comment: what extension are you talking about?

Comment: What does **EmailAsUsername** have to do with this?